# Segmentation Fault - pthread mutex locking issue

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, kdb

I am creating a simple kdb+ shared library which generates values on a seperate thread and executes a callback function when data is ready.  The application is writing data to a file descriptor in the new thread and reading from this in the main event loop.  The application appears to be segfaulting when trying to lock and unlock the mutex.

If I introduce a small sleep into the loop, the segfault seems to disappear.  This would suggest that the `pthread_mutex_lock` call is not blocking the thread until a lock is obtained as I would have expected.

```
#include <k.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PIPE_CAPACITY 65536

static int fd;
static pthread_t thread;
static pthread_mutex_t lock;

K callback(int d)
{
    K data;

    // Aquire mutex lock and read from fd
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    read(d, &data, PIPE_CAPACITY);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    // kdb+ callback
    k(0, (char *)"callback", r1(data), (K)0);

    return (K)0;
}

void* loop()
{
    while (1) {
        struct timespec ts;
        struct tm *time;

        // Get seconds and nanoseconds since epoch
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

        // Adjust for kdb+
        time = gmtime(&ts.tv_sec);
        time->tm_sec = 0;
        time->tm_min = 0;
        time->tm_hour = 0;
        ts.tv_sec -= mktime(time); // Subtract seconds between epoch and midnight

        // Create kdb+ timestamp
        K data = ktj(-KN, ts.tv_sec * 1000000000 + ts.tv_nsec);

        // Aquire mutex lock and write to fd
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        write(fd, &data, sizeof(K));
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}

K init()
{
    // Initialize mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

    // Create file descriptor
    fd = eventfd(0, 0);

    // Register callback
    sd1(fd, callback);

    // Launch thread
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, loop, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Not related, but you really should avoid one letter typenames such as `K`.

Comment: Can you provide the "main" function? Does initialization take effect before thread creation?

Comment: @MichaelWalz This is down to the API I have to work with, not my personal choice - contained in [k.h](http://code.kx.com/wsvn/code/kx/kdb%2B/c/c/k.h)

Comment: @Emisilve86 This is a shared library, there is no main function.  The entry point will be `init`.

Comment: @AnthonyGraham Fyi, `gmtime` is not thread-safe. You should use `gmtime_r` if offered on your platform (which is highly likely, since you're threading). Or `gmtime_s` if using a C11 compliant toolchain.

Comment: @AnthonyGraham i had this problem too and i was very very very confused about it...... finally i find your best question..... your very good....................... thankfulllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that K is a pointer type defined in k.h as:

```
typedef struct k0{..}*K;
```

This means you are sending a pointer to an object created in the "loop" thread to the callback executed in the main thread.  This does not work because kdb+ uses a separate memory pull for each thread.  I would recommend passing a copy of the data instead.

Another problem is at the line

```
read(d, &data, PIPE_CAPACITY);
```

You are reading 65536 bytes, but pass the address of an 8-byte variable as the destination.  The reason you don't get a segfault when you introduce the delay is that in this case the loop does not get a chance to write more than 8 bytes between the reads.

Finally, I am not sure you can use the file descriptor returned by eventfd as a read-write buffer.  I would recommend using the good old pipe() call.

The following modification of your code works for me:

```
#include <k.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int fd[2];
static pthread_t thread;
static pthread_mutex_t lock;

K callback(int d)
{
    K data = ktj(-KN, 0);

    // Aquire mutex lock and read from fd
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    read(d, (void *)&data->j, sizeof(data->j));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    // kdb+ callback
    k(0, (char *)"callback", data, (K)0);

    return (K)0;
}

void* loop()
{
    while (1) {
        struct timespec ts;
        struct tm *time;

        // Get seconds and nanoseconds since epoch
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

        // Adjust for kdb+
        time = gmtime(&ts.tv_sec);
        time->tm_sec = 0;
        time->tm_min = 0;
        time->tm_hour = 0;
        ts.tv_sec -= mktime(time); // Subtract seconds between epoch and midnight

        // Create kdb+ timestamp
        J data = (J)ts.tv_sec * 1000000000 + ts.tv_nsec;

        // Aquire mutex lock and write to fd
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        write(fd[1], &data, sizeof(data));
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}

K1(init)
{
    // Initialize mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

    // Create file descriptor
    pipe(fd);

    // Register callback
    sd1(fd[0], callback);

    // Launch thread
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, loop, NULL);

    R ktj(0, 0);
}
```

To test, copy the code above in x.c, compile

```
$ gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -I $(pwd) -DKXVER=3 x.c -o x.so
```

and run the following q code:

```
callback:0N!
init:`:./x 2:(`init;1)
init[]
```

Comment: `read(d, (void *)&data->j, sizeof(data->j));` yessssssssssssssssss. thats it you help me seriously with this statement thank you sooooooooooooooooooooooo much..... i had this `segmentation fault` with every mutex.lock and i had a read function from socket...................